# Group numpy matrix based on value of particular column, only on row indices from given array

Tags: python, list, numpy, matrix, numpy-slicing

I have a numpy matrix consisting of binary values. I have a list of row indices as well. Now I have to obtain indices from the matrix where the value for a particular column is 1, and the indices must be contained in the row indices list. What will be an efficient way of doing this? I'm currently doing:

```
result = [index for index in np.where(dataset[:, col] == 1)[0] if index in indices]
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe looping through the list of row indices is faster since you don't need to loop over all the rows of the matrix:

```
result = [index for index in indices if dataset[index, col] == 1]
```